# Portlet with angular-ui/ui-sortable

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, portal

I am trying to use angular-ui/ui-sortable for a portal application.
My application will be similar to the portlet example given in Jquery UI sortable [JQuery UI Sortable Portlets](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets).

Is it possible for some one to give an example or point me in the right direction  to implement this  with angular-ui/ui-sortable? 
I asked this question in the angular-ui/ui-sortable and they referred me to Stack Overflow [Issue portlets example #356](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/356)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using connected lists should serve your purpose if I understand what you're looking for:

[example pen](http://codepen.io/davidpm/pen/gagzJy)

```
    <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container screen floatleft" ng-model="list1">
      <div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list1">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
    </div>
    <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container screen floatleft" ng-model="list2">
      <div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list2">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
    </div>
    <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container screen floatleft" ng-model="list3">
      <div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list3">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I up voted and accepted it as answer. I am not very familiar with this stackflow system. Sorry about that.